# robots.txt allow crawling of category/product pages and js/css/images

Tags: robots.txt

I'm new to configuring robots.txt and trying to understand how to best configure for our Magento EE install. Right now, I have the following:

```
### bots should have full access to category/product url-key paths
### bots should have full access to media (images), skin (images/js/css), js directories

User-agent: *
### Directories
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /var/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
### Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /*?
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /catalog/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /onestepcheckout/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /wishlist/
### Files
Disallow: /api.php
Disallow: /apc_clear.php
Disallow: /index.php
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /get.php
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /pi.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_EE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE_EE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_SMD_ColorSwatch.txt
Disallow: /RELEASE_NOTES.txt

Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap/sitemap.xml
```

Agents should still be able to crawl all clean web page URLs, like CMS pages and category/product url-key paths, correct? For example, these URLs/pages would not be blocked and are still crawlable:

```
www.example.com/shape/fedora/            #category view page  
www.example.com/shape/fedora/cool-hat    #product view page  
www.example.com/some-cms-page/url-key    #CMS page
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hans2103/5729749 & https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en should help.

Comment: Thanks B00MER, the Google web master tools are just what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reckon Inchoo gives a good overview as well, with different options and examples to learn from

```
Inchoo’s recommended Magento robots.txt boilerplate:

# Google Image Crawler Setup
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:

# Crawlers Setup
User-agent: *

# Directories
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
#Disallow: /js/
#Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
#Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /shell/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/

# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
#Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/
Disallow: /catalog/product/gallery/

# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt

# Paths (no clean URLs)
#Disallow: /*.js$
#Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?SID=
```

Source [Click here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/ultimate-magento-robots-txt-file-examples/)

Comment: I would like to block category page URLs that contain query string parameters for sorting and filtering, E.g. `?dir=asc&order=price&size=56`. So if the URL contains `dir`, `order`, `size` parameters in query string, I want it blocked, while any other parameters are okay.

Comment: ya thats a good point, you would need to modify it then. If you have a solution it would be great if you can post it

Answer (score 0):

The reason the Google crawlers couldn't access our pages was because they were crawling with query string URLs, which `Disallow: /*?` blocks. @Thomas answer allows all query strings (minus `?SID=`). So while that would work, I want to block all URLs that contain sorting and filtering parameters in query strings to prevent duplicated crawled/indexed content, but allow any other parameters (tracking parameters, etc). Here's what I did:

```
#Removed
#Disallow: /*?

#Added
Disallow: /*?*dir=
Disallow: /*?*order=
Disallow: /*?*size=
Disallow: /*?*shape=
Disallow: /*?*color_filter=
Disallow: /*?*color=
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the 1 in a million, post out there !

A great robots.txt configuring compiled on "how to make best configure" for any website.

This question is resolved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407367/googlebot-is-adding-prefix-end-of-domain-whateveryouwritehere-with-http-status

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to answer the question. Please update your answer with whatever is relevant to this question. Links tend to go 404 over time, so it's best to post contents here.