# Magento2: How to allow the site to crawl the pages

Tags: magento2

Here is my Robots.txt file

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: abc.com/sitemap.xml
```

But the pages are still blocked. Please suggest is there any other options in Magento admin to enable this.

Thanks

Comment: refer this link if it's relevant to you 

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64026/robots-txt-allow-crawling-of-category-product-pages-and-js-css-images**